# multipart/form-data hidden value passing to php in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, multipartform-data

I am not able pass the value from hidden element of form to PHP. The form is `multipart/form-data`. The same is working fine if I change the form to normal.

The ajax code given below

```
var form=$(this);
var dat=$('form')[0];    
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'), // get type of request from 'method'
        url: form.attr('action'), // get url of request from 'action'
        data: new FormData(dat), // dataform 
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {}
})
```

the hidden field form code is

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="21">
  <input name="confirmation" type="hidden" id="confirmation" value="">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm valid" id="user_login" name="user_login" readonly="readonly" aria-invalid="false">
</div>
```

The entire form is so big, so I posted only the hidden field part.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots of code, but the actual code, formatted in code blocks (`{}` button in the [edit] mode). Also post all relevant code, e.g what is `dat` in `new FormData(dat)`, are your inputs wrapped in a `<form>` element?

Comment: Is there are reason you're passing false for `contentType` instead of `'multipart/form-data'`? There is no `enctype` property on [`ajax` settings](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Comment: Tried serialize() ?
data = $( "form" ).serialize();

Comment: the form contains image upload. so enctype: multipart/form-data, is used. in data = $( "form" ).serialize(); method is working. not able to upload the image